# how do i intercept popups in ionic framework?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to play a sound for every popup(may be `$ionicPopup`) in my app, but I don't want to insert code everywhere. Is there a way to config once? Can I intercept it?

Comment: You can write a service or a directive for this.

Comment: You mean wrapping `$ionicPopup`? I can do that if I have that in mind at the beginning, but now we've already got code calling `$ionicPopup` everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could monkey patch the $ionicPopup service pretty easily.

Put something like this in a run block so that it gets executed at startup:

```
var _show = $ionicPopup.show;
$ionicPopup.show = function (options) {
    playAudio();
    return _show(options);
};
```